# What is the best approach to design AWS lambda function for CRUD operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

For a CRUD application what would be the best approach to design AWS lambda function:

1. Create a single lambda function and differentiate each call with a switch case in the handler.
2. Create a single lambda function but with a separate handler for each call. Is it possible even?
3. Create a separate lambda function for each operation.

As these are just simple CRUD operations, size is not a big factor. But I am bit concerns with the managing and cost-effectiveness.

Comment: You didn't say which programming language you're using or which, if any, framework. Typically you would use API Gateway and it's common see a Flask app (Python) or an Express app (Node.js) with a single entry point and some form of annotation or middleware that itself does the routing by HTTP method and URL.

Comment: Language is Python and I am not considering any framework as it is pretty straightforward for the CRUD operation. And yes, I am using API Gateway.

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537449/aws-gateway-many-api-routes-to-single-lambda-integration-each-endpoint-mapping-t), albeit Java.

Answer (score 4):

We usually go with your Approach #3 - having a separate lambda function for each operation. And to overcome the concerns of code management, we use [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/).

And we expose the Lambda functions to clients using API Gateway. So the requests look like this -

```
/createUser API -> CreateUserLambdaFunction
/getUser API -> GetUserLambdaFunction
...
...
```

And the code structure is like this -

**index.js** (Handlers for all lambda functions)

```
import { DbAccessor } from './accessors/db-accessor';
exports.create_user = async(event) => {
  ...
  DbAccessor.createUser(event..)
}
exports.get_user = async(event) => {
  ...
  DbAccessor.getUser(event..)
}
```

**db-accessor.js**

```
Common file for all Lambda functions. contains all the CRUD interactions with the db.
```

And finally to stitch all of this together and deploy all Lambda functions at once, we use AWS SAM. SAM requires one template.yml file to contain the definitions of all AWS Resources that need to be created, in our case, it is API Gateway and Lambda functions.

**template.yml**

```
Resources:
    ApiGateway:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
        Properties:
            StageName: Prod
            DefinitionBody:
                swagger: '2.0'
                info:
                    version: '1.0'
                    title: 'UserService'
                paths:
                    /createUser:
                        post:
                            responses: {}
                            x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                                httpMethod: post
                                type: aws_proxy
                                uri:
                                    Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${CreateUser.Arn}/invocations
                   /getUser:
                        post:
                            responses: {}
                            x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                                httpMethod: post
                                type: aws_proxy
                                uri:
                                    Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${GetUser.Arn}/invocations

    CreateUser:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: .
            Handler: index.create_user
            Runtime: nodejs10.x
    GetUser:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: .
            Handler: index.get_user
            Runtime: nodejs10.x
```

Following are some benefits we see with this approach over the other two that you mentioned -

- Having separate Lambda functions enables us to have separate CloudWatch logs  which makes it easier to debug in case of issues.
- Using SAM templates (or CloudFormation), it is easier to manage the release process for the entire application. We don't have to deploy the functions separately.
- It is easier to set up different monitoring rules, alarming criteria, notifications for different Lambda functions.

Comment: That's a great answer. Thank you!